# Where is an image saved when uploaded via the admin?

Tags: image, django-admin

I am practising with Django, so I am a beginner, and trying to build a shopping cart app, I came across the problem of uploading an image.

Now, before actually implementing a page where you can add new products, I am using the admin side to create new items which, of course, have an image field.

I was wondering when uploading an image from the admin, where is the actual file stored?

I had a quick look in venv/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img which looked to me like the right candidate, but It seems to be the wrong directory.

I am curious about this because temporarily, I would like to use bootstrap's card, and of course, I have to specify a source directory for displaying images.

Thanks for any clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

For dev env.
Files are loaded to `settings.MEDIA_ROOT`

Read: [Should I upload images to a static directory in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457774/should-i-upload-images-to-a-static-)
Read2: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/